# Java synchronized: just keep critical sections small?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I'm doing some basic experiments to evaluate synchronized blocks' overhead.
I'm quite perplexes about the results, hence the question.

In the code below, a number of threads test and increment a global counter (up to a goal number) in a so called critical section. 
Moreover, an additional configurable load of work can be executed inside or outside the critical section.

Playing with constants, particularly with `LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION` and `LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION`, what I'm observing is that the overhead introduced by the synchronized block can be appreciated only for big
amounts of work INSIDE the critical section.
See these two output examples:

```
Processors: 4
NUM_OF_THREADS: 4
LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION: 1000000
LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION: 100
NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL: 10000
Non synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: 6370 milliseconds.
Synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: 6355 milliseconds.
```

and

```
Processors: 4
NUM_OF_THREADS: 4
LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION: 100
LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION: 1000000
NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL: 10000
Non synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: 6351 milliseconds.
Synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: 18629 milliseconds.
```

As you can see, the synchronization overhead seems to happen only for high `LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION`.
This is not confusing per se and, of course, confirms that keeping critical sections small is a good practice. 
But given that, for the good practice, it is uncommon to have big critical sections, this result clashes with the common opinion of avoiding the synchronized keyword in code as much as possible. I would say instead that synchronization keyword is always safe for small amount of work in the critical section.

So I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong, in my code or in my head. Could you please help me to clarify?

Below is the code I've used for testing. 
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Best Regards,
John

OS: Windows 7
Java version: 1.7.0_67 (32 bit)

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long startMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL = 10000L;
        final int LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION = 1000000;
        final int LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION = 100;
        final int NUM_OF_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

        System.out.println("Processors: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        System.out.println("NUM_OF_THREADS: " + NUM_OF_THREADS);
        System.out.println("LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION: " + LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION);
        System.out.println("LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION: " + LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION);
        System.out.println("NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL: " + NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL);

        doConcurrentJob(NUM_OF_THREADS, startMilliseconds, NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL, LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION, LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION);

        //Reset state
        startMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CounterThread.goalGlobalCounter = 0;
        CounterThread.goalReached = false;

        doConcurrentSynchronizedJob(NUM_OF_THREADS, startMilliseconds, NUM_OF_JOBS_GOAL, LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION, LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION);

    }

    static void doConcurrentJob(int numOfThreads, long startMilliseconds, long numOfJobsGoal, int loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, int loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection) throws Exception {
        CounterThread[] counterThreads = new CounterThread[numOfThreads];
        while (!CounterThread.goalReached) {
            for (int i = 0; i < counterThreads.length; i++) {
                if (counterThreads[i] == null || !counterThreads[i].isAlive()) {
                    counterThreads[i] = new CounterThread(numOfJobsGoal, loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection);
                    counterThreads[i].start();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Non synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMilliseconds) + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.flush();
        for (int i = 0; i < counterThreads.length; i++) {
            counterThreads[i].join();
        }
    }

    static void doConcurrentSynchronizedJob(int numOfThreads, long startMilliseconds, long numOfJobsGoal, int loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, int loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection) throws Exception {
        CounterThreadSynchronized[] counterThreadsSyncronized = new CounterThreadSynchronized[numOfThreads];
        while (!CounterThread.goalReached) {
            for (int i = 0; i < counterThreadsSyncronized.length; i++) {
                if (counterThreadsSyncronized[i] == null || !counterThreadsSyncronized[i].isAlive()) {
                    counterThreadsSyncronized[i] = new CounterThreadSynchronized(startMilliseconds, numOfJobsGoal, loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection);
                    counterThreadsSyncronized[i].start();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMilliseconds) + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.flush();
        for (int i = 0; i < counterThreadsSyncronized.length; i++) {
            counterThreadsSyncronized[i].join();
        }
    }
}

class CounterThread extends Thread {

    public static int goalGlobalCounter = 0;
    public static boolean goalReached;

    public final long GOAL;
    protected final int LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION;
    private final int LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION;

    protected int fooSpinner;

    public CounterThread(long numOfJobsGoal, int loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, int loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection) {
        this.GOAL = numOfJobsGoal;
        this.LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION = loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection;
        this.LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION = loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (long i = 0; i < LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION; i++) {
            fooSpinner++;
        }
        executeCriticalSection();
    }

    public void executeCriticalSection() {

        for (long i = 0; i < LOAD_OF_WORK_INSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION; i++) {
            fooSpinner++;
        }
        if (goalGlobalCounter < GOAL) {
            goalGlobalCounter++;
        } else {
            goalReached = true;

        }
    }

}

class CounterThreadSynchronized extends CounterThread {

    protected static final Object globalMutex = new Object();

    public CounterThreadSynchronized(long startMilliseconds, long numOfJobsGoal, int loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, int loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection) {
        super(numOfJobsGoal, loadOfWorkOutsideCriticalSection, loadOfWorkInsideCriticalSection);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (long i = 0; i < LOAD_OF_WORK_OUTSIDE_CRITICAL_SECTION; i++) {
            fooSpinner++;
        }
        synchronized (globalMutex) {
            executeCriticalSection();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

Mike Nakis: I've copy-pasted your code and don't have the same kind of results as yours. Below are the logs of 10 consecutive runs with TEST_DURATION = 1000.

```
Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  494682730
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  515156056
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  520437287
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  135192560
     10  |      10  |   false   |  499448540
     10  |      10  |    true   |   64254608
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  519790639
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  507597477
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  520784275
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  133563124
     10  |      10  |   false   |  510318548
     10  |      10  |    true   |   66006750
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  512302804
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  514999373
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  526430883
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  132596432
     10  |      10  |   false   |  506235601
     10  |      10  |    true   |   66220700
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  505257231
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  512668300
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  528309859
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  133947238
     10  |      10  |   false   |  518984983
     10  |      10  |    true   |   63617110
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  522235388
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  502896342
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  515668568
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  130705136
     10  |      10  |   false   |  514470943
     10  |      10  |    true   |   60617050
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  517828858
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  515355048
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  512963551
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  134235958
     10  |      10  |   false   |  515017236
     10  |      10  |    true   |   62228490
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  521690615
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  527830725
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  512735126
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  134278503
     10  |      10  |   false   |  507281283
     10  |      10  |    true   |   63333950
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  515604517
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  529685270
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  520260430
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  131993844
     10  |      10  |   false   |  505190996
     10  |      10  |    true   |   66865140
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  522747273
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  530824975
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  536263165
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  131938210
     10  |      10  |   false   |  502281027
     10  |      10  |    true   |   64480710
Done.

Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  523386208
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  511467042
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  512778324
     10  |   10000  |    true   |  133751262
     10  |      10  |   false   |  513257782
     10  |      10  |    true   |   61573350
Done.
```

As the title of my question suggests, I'm mainly interested in low "inside"/"outside" ratio, that is to say the first two configurations of the output. Looking at the output, can't honestly say that in any case locking is slower than non-locking.

Comment: Have you tried with both "inside" and "outside" being 100? Can you please show the result?

Comment: Results with syncronization might vary a lot with the level of contention. Of course synchronized is optimized, so it's as fast as it can be, while still guaranteeing correctness. My guideline would be to only use synchronization when needed (i.e. where you will have multithread access and you can't use segregation or immutability), and then only try to optimize it if you really profile it to be your bottleneck.

Comment: You're also trying with 4 threads, so no big deal, they can approx. have 1 core each, being all active at the same time. The real issue comes when an active thread has to stop, because the thread owning the mutex is not currently running, and will not be for a long time, due to high contention.

Comment: @Mike runned a few time. Last result was: Non synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: 536 milliseconds.
Synchronized - Goal reached, elapsed time: 527 milliseconds. Giulio: if I raise the number of threads the result is the same. I've tried with 40 and 400, for example.

Comment: @Johnca your code is somewhat unnecessarily convoluted and therefore it is hard to verify that it is correct.  One thing I can point right away is that you should be incrementing a volatile variable, otherwise the JIT may optimize your entire loop into `fooSpinner += constant`.

Comment: I have a more simple and better program here: http://ideone.com/8wa72Q (Be sure to copy it and run it locally though, because on ideone it is sharing the server with lots and lots of other threads.)

Comment: Well, either your machine is 3 times faster than mine, or there is something funny going on.  Anyhow, your results are proportionally very similar to mine. What this tells us is that a very brief and very infrequently entered critical section causes negligible blocking, which is not surprising at all.  But are you sure that your code will be running in a scenario where the work done outside of the critical section will be 3 orders of magnitude larger than the work done inside? Perhaps you should retry with a smaller difference.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends because the definition of "small" is very different from problem to problem. Fortunately there's [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) to give you clarity on this.

> Amdahl's law states that if P is the proportion of a program that can be made parallel, and (1 − P) is the proportion that cannot be parallelized, then the maximum speedup that can be achieved by using N processors is S(N) = 1 / ((1-P) + P/N)

"critical session" would constitute "proportion that cannot be parallelized", hence the longer you make it, the lower the potential throughput gain you *could potentially* achieve through parallelization.

In practice this isn't so clear cut. For example, the overhead of locking may be greater than the theoretical gain. For this reason, JVMs sometime perform "lock coarsening" which will actually make the critical section longer, but reduce the overall overhead.

Comment: Hi Enno. My problem is not that I cannot explain why an overhead arises in case of big critical sections, but why I can't see any overhead in case of small critical sections and high contention. Overhead should be there and in my opinion should be observable also with simple home testing. So I think the problem is in my code but I can't say where.

Comment: @Johnca: there's many reason why a micro benchmark won't give you correct results. I'd recommend reading Java Concurrency in Practice's section on performance testing. Also, as it stands your code has parts that aren't thread-safe. It's hard to say anything as the behavior will be implementation dependent etc.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should not put code in synchronization block unnecessarily but, for performance reason you shouldn't break your functionality like in producer consumer problem there must be some synchronization between producer and consumer yes of-course it is little bit overhead to keep lock and all the required stuff for synchronization but its required. else your system will not behave in exacted way and there is no mean of performance in that case.

so long story in short use synchronization only when its required.

Answer (score 0):

The common opinion of avoiding the synchronized keyword in code as much as possible does of course still hold, for two reasons, one having to do with performance, the other being completely unrelated to performance.

With regards to performance:

When your critical sections are as small as possible you reduce the chances of contention, but you do not eliminate them. The chances of contention then depend more on how often the threads attempt to enter the critical section, rather than for how long they stay in it.  Every time a thread attempts to enter a critical section while another thread happens to already be in it, you take a huge performance penalty.

But a much more important issue, which is unrelated to performance, is this:

Locking (the synchronized keyword) is something that only highly experienced programmers can do, and even their code is virtually untestable, so it is essentially just a bunch of bugs waiting to happen. There is no formal methodology which can guarantee that locking code is bug-free, and this is especially bad in light of the fact that there exists at least one methodology which can in fact guarantee this. (Immutable message passing.)

EDIT

I found the behavior of Johnca's program kind of weird, so I went ahead and adapted his program to make it more useful, easier to understand, and possibly more correct.  Here it is:

```
class SynchronizationTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        SynchronizationTest program = new SynchronizationTest();
        program.run();
    }

    static final long BIG_NUMBER = 10_000L;
    static final long SMALL_NUMBER = 10L;
    static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    static final int TEST_DURATION = 500;

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Processors: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + " Threads: " + NUM_OF_THREADS );
        System.out.println( "Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done" );
        doConcurrentJob( BIG_NUMBER, SMALL_NUMBER, false );
        doConcurrentJob( BIG_NUMBER, SMALL_NUMBER, true );
        doConcurrentJob( SMALL_NUMBER, BIG_NUMBER, false );
        doConcurrentJob( SMALL_NUMBER, BIG_NUMBER, true );
        doConcurrentJob( SMALL_NUMBER, SMALL_NUMBER, false );
        doConcurrentJob( SMALL_NUMBER, SMALL_NUMBER, true );
        System.out.println( "Done." );
    }

    static void doConcurrentJob( long outside, long inside, boolean useLocking ) throws Exception
    {
        MyThread[] myThreads = new MyThread[NUM_OF_THREADS];
        boolean[] stopFlag = { false };
        for( int i = 0; i < myThreads.length; i++ )
            myThreads[i] = new MyThread( outside, inside, useLocking, stopFlag );
        for( MyThread myThread : myThreads )
            myThread.start();
        Thread.sleep( TEST_DURATION );
        stopFlag[0] = true;
        for( MyThread myThread : myThreads )
            myThread.join();
        long sumOfWorkDone = 0;
        for( MyThread myThread : myThreads )
            sumOfWorkDone += myThread.workDone;
        System.out.printf( "%7d  | %7d  |   %5b   | %10d\n", outside, inside, useLocking, sumOfWorkDone );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( "ClassExplicitlyExtendsThread" )
    static class MyThread extends Thread
    {
        protected static final Object GLOBAL_MUTEX = new Object();
        private final long outside;
        private final long inside;
        private final boolean useSynchronization;
        volatile int workDone = 0;
        private final boolean[] stopFlag;

        MyThread( long outside, long inside, boolean useSynchronization, boolean[] stopFlag )
        {
            this.outside = outside;
            this.inside = inside;
            this.useSynchronization = useSynchronization;
            this.stopFlag = stopFlag;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings( "RefusedBequest" )
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while( !stopFlag[0] )
            {
                doWork( outside );
                if( useSynchronization )
                {
                    //noinspection SynchronizationOnStaticField
                    synchronized( GLOBAL_MUTEX )
                    {
                        doWork( inside );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    doWork( inside );
                }
            }
        }

        private void doWork( long amount )
        {
            for( long i = 0L; i < amount; i++ )
            {
                if( stopFlag[0] )
                    break;
                //noinspection NonAtomicOperationOnVolatileField
                workDone++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results on my machine using TEST_DURATION = 1000 are:

```
Processors: 4 Threads: 4
Outside  |  Inside  |  Locking  |  Work Done
  10000  |      10  |   false   |  181081027
  10000  |      10  |    true   |  149043896
     10  |   10000  |   false   |  210331458
     10  |   10000  |    true   |   58841199
     10  |      10  |   false   |  230592182
     10  |      10  |    true   |   38739670
Done.
```

The way I interpret the above results is as follows:

1. In all cases, locking is slower than non-locking, but the results vary.
2. When the work done outside the critical section is large, and the work done inside is small, then it rarely happens that a thread will attempt to acquire a lock while another thread already has the lock, so the difference is small, but still the non-locking code gets more work done.
3. When the work done outside the critical section is small, and the work done inside is large, the locking code performs even worse, because threads are usually waiting for other threads to let go of the critical section.
4. When the work done outside and inside is small, the locking code performs even worse, because threads usually manage to get very little work done before they have to retry the critical section at which point they usually find it locked and have to wait.

The truth, however, is that I would expect to find the differences even more pronounced.  I would expect the differences to be a few orders of magnitude rather than within the same order of magnitude.  I do not know why this is happening.  Perhaps my code is not correct, either.  At least it is easier to verify.

Comment: Regarding performance I totally agree, and this is one of the reason for this little experiment: I would like to appreciate the overhead with some tests. But I can't with my code. I think I've coded in a way that causes high contention, but still I can't appreciate the overhead unless I setup a "big" load of work inside the critical section. Why?

Comment: Mike, thanks for your considerations. Could you please make the workDone variable static in your code and run your test again? Making it shared among threads is a more realistic way of testing critical sections and, for what I've seen so far while still not knowing the reason, leads to different conclusions. Of course if you make workDone static you must also initialize it to zero at the beginning of each doConcurrentJob method, and the sumOfWorkDone must be simply set to it.

Comment: It cannot be made static because it will then be modified by multiple threads, and the increment operation is not atomic, so the value will be messed up.  Luckily, it does not need to be made static: the critical section is tested by the `synchronized( GLOBAL_MUTEX )` clause, there is no need to do anything else.

Comment: Right. I'll try with static AtomicInteger. It may have some low level locking cost, but it is ok for speed comparations because would be equally paid inside both synchronized and not synchronized critical sections.

Comment: Just tried your code (no static, no Atomic)  and added my results.

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't use the synchronized keyword and instead use the java.concurrent package, which provides a bit higher level primitives like Reentrant locks, read/write locks, optimistic locking, and more.

Also, you should be aware that hotspot does a lot of optimization under the hood which ends up removing locks when they are not needed. This might explain your results.

Finally, your fields are not marked as volatile and you may have a few issues lurking there as well.

Concurrency is hard, even if you know your stuff.

Comment: I would argue that `ReentrantLock` is a _lower_ level of abstraction than the `synchronized` keyword, not higher.  And that's the source of its power:  You can use it in ways that you can't do with the more structured `synchronized` mechanism.  E.g., you can lock a lock in one method and unlock it in a different method, and you can get more than one condition variable for the same lock.  Of course, with more power comes more risk...